# Use Automapper to map from a list of objects to a single object using property values from source

Tags: c#, automapper

Source:

```
public class Message 
{
    public DateTime AcceptedDate { get; set; }
    public List<PriceDetail> PriceDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PriceDetail 
{
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
    public string ServiceValue { get; set; }
}
```

Destination:

```
public class GroupEntity 
{
    public DateTime AcceptedDate { get; set; }
    public List<PlanEntity> Plans { get; set; }
}

public class PlanEntity 
{
    public string MetalLevel { get; set; }
    public string MdCode { get; set; }
    public string RxCode { get; set; }
    public string PercentChange { get; set; }
}
```

Source PriceDetail could be something like:

- ServiceCode = "MetalLevel"
- ServiceValue = "Gold"

I need to map PriceDetail to PlanEntity such:

- if PriceDetail.ServiceCode = "MetalLevel" then map it to PlanEntity.MetalLevel
- if PriceDetail.ServiceCode = "RxCode" then map it to PlanEntity.RxCode
- etc..

I understand there will be hard coded logic in the mapper, but not sure how or if this is possible using automapper.  Any tips or suggestion are very much appreciated.

Comment: you need write this logic where you want to map your items. In mapper it is impossible IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateMap<PriceDetail, PlanEntity>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.MetalLevel, opt => {
               opt.PreCondition(src => src.ServiceCode=="MetalLevel");
               opt.MapFrom(src => src.ServiceCode);
           });
CreateMap<PriceDetail, PlanEntity>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.RxCode, opt => {
               opt.PreCondition(src => src.ServiceCode=="RxCode");
               opt.MapFrom(src => src.ServiceCode);
           });
```